# Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине могут не работать кнопки в мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении мышкой на картинку с правильно заданной href курсор никак не изменяется и при нажатии ничего не происходит. Иногда, при нажатии на боковую часть картинки, переход всё-таки происходит. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: картинка накрыта другим элементом, который наполз на нее в мобильной версии

Comment: Здравствуйте. Первое, что сразу нужно попробовать это задать ссылке с картинкой: 'display: block'. Если не помогает, то выложить здесь свой код.

Comment: Огромнейшее вам спасибо. Проблема была из-за того, что контейнер перекрывал картинки.

Answer (score 2):

Kартинка накрыта другим элементом, который наполз на нее в мобильной версии.

Comment: Поставил плюс за экстрасенсорные способности)